# Extending Classes in Kotlin's Generics

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement this enum with simple constructor as follows:

```
enum class WithGraphicKind(val innerClass: Class<*>) {
    CONTACT(Contact::class.java), SALE(Sale::class.java);
}
```

As both `Contact` and `Sale` classes implement a common interface `WithGraphics`, I would like to type the constructor as `innerClass: Class<WithGraphics>`, however that does not work. I also tried `Class<* : WithGraphics>` and similar others, but nothing works. I also couldn't find any hint in official documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need declaration-site variance [Kotlin Generics: Declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

If you tell the compiler that you'll only consume WithGraphics, the compiler allows any subtype of WithGraphics

```
enum class WithGraphicKind(val innerClass: Class<out WithGraphics>) {
    CONTACT(Contact::class.java), SALE(Sale::class.java);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
enum class WithGraphicKind(val innerClass: Class<out WithGraphics>)
```

which is basically the equivalent to Java's

```
Class<? extends WithGraphics>
```